# Rain Fall Prediction using time series algorithm

Tags: python

```
dataset=pd.read_csv("rainfall in india 1901-2015.csv")
#parse strings to datetime type
dataset['YEAR']=pd.to_datetime(dataset['YEAR'],infer_datetime_format=True) 
indexedDataset = dataset.set_index(['YEAR'])

plt.xlabel("Date") 
plt.ylabel("Number of air passengers") 
plt.plot(indexedDataset)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 plt.xlabel("Date")
>         2 plt.ylabel("Number of air passengers")
>   ----> 3 plt.plot(indexedDataset)
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.pyplot` cannot plot a raw dataframe like you are giving it. You either need to give it one array for the X axis and one for the Y axis or either use the pandas plotting tool.

```
# option 1
indexedDataset.plot(x="YEAR", y="passenger column name")

# option 2
plt.plot(indexedDataset["YEAR"].values, indexedDataset["passenger column name"].values)
```